# jQuery: how to get 'this' context without adding event listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am working in Angular 4 app, consider following scenario.

jQuery code:

```
toggle(this: any) {
  $(this).siblings('.legends').slideToggle();
}
```

html code:

```
<div (click)="toggle(this)"></div>
```

I know, this doesn't work, What I want to achieve is that, How to get `this` context that can be used in jQuery without adding a event listener like `$(".toggleBtn").on('click',function () {});` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I got the answer,

jQuery code:

```
toggle(event: any) {
  $(event.target).siblings('.legends').slideToggle();
}
```

Html Code:

```
<div (click)="toggle($event)"></div>
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

> event.target (version added: 1.0)
>
> Description: The DOM element that initiated the event.
>
> The target property can be the element that registered for the event
>   or a descendant of it. It is often useful to compare event.target to
>   this in order to determine if the event is being handled due to event
>   bubbling. This property is very useful in event delegation, when
>   events bubble